# Making a custom button view animation effect with Thread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, button

In my main activity I have a button with the text "Play". I want the text to gradually grow and then gradually diminish in size. This should loop until the button is clicked. This effect should appear like a gentle glow.

So, I have tried using a Thread to accomplish this:

```
// Play Button Animation Thread
Thread playAnimation = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            int textSize = 25;
            while (textSize <= 50) {
                playBtn.setTextSize(textSize);
                textSize += .10;
                sleep(100);
            }   
        } 

        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        finally {

        }

    }
};
```

Then, I called the thread with:

```
playAnimation.start();
```

It isn't working as I have it, but now I'm thinking there is probably a better way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong with the code you have written:

1. You have declared your `textSize` variable as an `int`.  Thus, your attempt to increment the value by 0.1 each iteration is futile because the value is cast back to an int after each operation, dropping off the value you just added (i.e. 25 += 0.1 -> 25.1, cast back to an int -> 25...lather, rinse repeat).  So the value you are passing to `setTextSize()` never actually changes.
2. Your code does not repeat.  That loop will only run once until the value reaches 50, and then stop.  You won't get the back/forth effect you are going for.
3. Your updates to the UI should ALWAYS occur on the main/rendering thread.  You should never call any update methods (like `setTextSize()`) from any thread you have created.  This can be solved by employing a `Handler` to manage the threading for you.

If you want the **entire button** to animate, you can look at the animation framework like others have suggested.  However, to automate **just** the text size, you are on the right path...we just need to tweak your code based on the points I mentioned above:

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
boolean mReverse = false;
Runnable mUpdate = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    float current = playBtn.getTextSize();
    if(mReverse) {
      current -= 0.1;
      playBtn.setTextSize(current);
      mReverse = (current <= 25);
    } else {
      current += 0.1;
      playBtn.setTextSize(current);
      mReverse = (current >= 50);
    }

    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdate, 100);
  }
}
```

The `Handler` is created on the main thread, and all code inside the `Runnable` is executed on the main thread...so you may update the UI there.  `postDelayed()` takes care of the wait delays so you don't really need to create another thread at all.  To start your animation, just call

```
mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdate, 100);
```

anywhere in your code.  To stop the animation at any time, simply stop calling `postDelayed` after each iteration.

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Animation resources to perform the above task.

1. You need to create an animation resource file (anim_play.xml) and put it in res/anim folder.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:duration="1000"
      android:repeatCount="infinite"
      android:fromXScale="1.0"
      android:fromYScale="1.0"
      android:toXScale="1.2"
      android:toYScale="1.2" >
     </scale>
   ```
2. Set the animation to the particular view.

   ```
    play_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
    playAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_play); 
    play_btn.startAnimation(playAnim);
   ```
3. remove the animation when the user clicked the button.

   ```
       play_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           play_btn.clearAnimation();
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Look for [animations](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html) in android - it is best way to create simple effects.

About you code - changing of user interface are allowed only from main thread, so you can't create another thread for animation.